# ui-router -- data service called in view1 not showing in view2

Tags: angularjs, rest, web-services, spring-mvc, angular-ui-router

### Web service isn't working correctly, not sure if that is the issue

new to AngularJS and HTML in general and trying to figure out an additional issue to a previous question I had. What I am trying to do is to display the information from my web service onto the page I've created:

```
  $scope.clickFunc = function () {
    $scope.isNewSite = false;
    $scope.isModifySite = true;
    var siteId = Number($stateParams.siteId);
    SpringDataRestService.get(
        {
            "collection": "sites",
            "resource": siteId
        },
        function (response) {                   // Success Function
            $scope.targetEntity = response;
            $scope.retrieveEntitlementSites();

        }
    );

}
```

This method is called from myview1.html, with an ng-click:

```
<td data-title="'Name'" filter="{ name: 'text'}">
    <a ui-sref="app.SitesDetailsEdit({siteId:entity.id})" ui-sref-active="active"
       ng-click="clickFunc()">{{entity.name}}</a>
</td>
```

However, I don't understand why my GET isn't working correctly. I think it might be due to the fact the information that needs to be displayed is myview2.html, but the web service should be called regardless.

Any help would be great, and sorry if I'm not clear enough. Will try to provide more detail if I can.

Comment: post your service code and what is $scope.retrieveEntitlementSites();

Comment: EntitlementSites isn't irrelevant, should have deleted that sorry. What service code? The service code of the sites/siteId?

Comment: SpringDataRestService

Comment: **Describe the problem**. "Not working correctly" is not a problem description.

Comment: Problem is likely caused by `ng-click` and `ui-sref` being used together. State transition should be done *after* data returns from server. Use `$state.go` inside the service callback.

Answer (score 1):

View 1 has its own controller and View 2 has is own controller.  You'll need to emit the change from the service and listen to the change and update it with that value in View 2.  There's no way for the content in View 1 to translate to View 2 without a service talking to them.